# Understanding a theorem regarding "intermediate subgroups" between $\mathbb{Z}$ and $p\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: group-theory, proof-explanation

I'm trying to understand a theorem presented in an abstract algebra lecture video by Benedict Gross. The exact theorem is:

> If $K$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z} \supset K \supset p\mathbb{Z}$ for a prime $p$, then either $K = \mathbb{Z}$ or $K = p\mathbb{Z}$.

This relies on the fact, proved prior to this, that if $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and $K$ is a subgroup of $G$ containing $H$, then $K/H$ is a subgroup of $G/H$. I'm fine with that result, but there's a jump from there I'm not fully understanding. The proof (paraphrased) proceeds as follows.

> As $\mathbb{Z}$ is abelian, the subgroup $p\mathbb{Z}$ is normal. As $K$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ containing $K$, we have that $K/p\mathbb{Z}$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. By Lagrange's theorem, the order of $K/p\mathbb{Z}$ divides the order of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. As $p$ is prime, the order of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is $p$, the only positive divisors of which are $1$ and $p$. Therefore, either $|K/p\mathbb{Z}| = 1$ or $|K/p\mathbb{Z}| = p$.

At this point I'm having trouble working backwards from a statement regarding the order of the quotient with the order of $K$, the group being quotiented. I believe it has something to do with the fact that, in the setup where $K$ is a subgroup of $G$ containing $H$, $K$ can be regarding as the "union" of cosets corresponding to the subgroup $K/p\mathbb{Z}$, since these subgroups have to partition $K$. Gross writes this as the "inverse image" of the subgroup under the canonical quotient map $G \to G/H$. I'm not fully certain I understand this argument.

Comment: What you are forgetting is that you have a **correspondence** between subgroups. The trivial subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ corresponds to $p\mathbb{Z}$. The subgroup $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ corresponds to $\mathbb{Z}$. If $K/p\mathbb{Z}$ has cardinality $1$, then it is the trivial subgroup, so $K=p\mathbb{Z}$. If $K/p\mathbb{Z}$ has cardinality $p$, then it is the whole thing, so $K=\mathbb{Z}$. And as you have already established, this correspondence comes from the inverse image map to $\varphi\colon\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ (the canonical projection).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thank you, this is extremely helpful. Would you mind explaining a bit more about why $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ corresponds to $p\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ corresponds to $\mathbb{Z}$? I'm still having difficulty with this, even after trying to work the map $\varphi$ backwards.

Comment: There is one and only one subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ containing $p\mathbb{Z}$ whose image under the map $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ corresponds to the trivial subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, namely $p\mathbb{Z}$ (because $p\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is the trivial subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$). There is one and only one subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ containing $p\mathbb{Z}$ whose image under the map $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is the whole group, namely $\mathbb{Z}$.